# Inicializar modelo en angular

Tags: angular

Tengo un modelo de customer, que implementa un catalago y una entidad, pero al momento de hacer `this.customer =  new Customer(0, '', );` me pide parametros del catalogo. Pero no se que pasarle. Tienen alguna documentacion relacionado a esto? Apenas estoy iniciando, anexo mi codigo.

customer-component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.customer =  new Customer(0, '', );
  }
```

model customer:

```
import { Catalogbase } from "./catalogbase";

export class Customer extends Catalogbase{
   constructor(public idCustomer: number, public name: string, data: Catalogbase){
       super(data);
   }
}
```

CatalogBase:

```
import { IEntitybase, EntityBase } from "./entitybase";

export interface ICatalogbase extends IEntitybase {
    code: string;
    description: string;
    active: boolean;
    
}

export class Catalogbase extends EntityBase implements IEntitybase{
    code: string;
    description: string;
    active: boolean; 
    constructor(data: ICatalogbase){
        super(data);
        this.code = data.code;
        this.description = data.description;
        this.active = data.active;
    }
}
```

Comment: Te debe pedir un catalogbase como tercer parámetro. ¿Catalogbase tendrá algún constructor?

Comment: @GavilanPatagonico Lo anexo a la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la estructura en base a las interfaces y clases que compartes:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.customer = new Customer(0, '', new Catalogbase(
        'codigo',
        'una descripion',
        true;
      );
    }
```

En este caso todos esos campos son requeridos. Si omites alguno el compilador te dará error.

Comment: Me marca `Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts
catalogbase.ts(14, 17): An argument for 'data' was not provided.´ :(

Comment: @karlDomínguez Puedes poner toda la traza del error en texto? En tu pregunta. Y señalar cual es la linea 14.